# I need to invoke a process using process builder as another user....How can I do it?

Tags: java

I have to execute some process as a unprivileged user from my server.Thats my doubt

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the operating system you you will need to invoke [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) (Linux, *NIX and Mac) or [runas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) (windows)

**Edit**

Another option use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) - it basically compiles standard libraries to Java interfaces. I haven't used it, but if you are looking at using OS calls, you may want to explore this.

Answer (score 0):

In java there's only one way to invoke a process, that is by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)`. For anything else(privelege, permission, etc...) you may need to use JNI.

Comment: This is not true. Runtime.getRuntime().exec() was superseded/amended by the ProcessBuilder in Java 5 which provides some more convenient methods.